# Which formula can add the same word next to the query result lines // example

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I made an example to support what I am trying to explain in the title.
File is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yD49_As8nM6gLq2A1J9eEEoIVZadxfVQBq-LPSDIPLA/edit#gid=0

The objective is : I query a database. I would like to come up with a formula which includes this query and adds a given word (here Classe 1) in front of each resulting line of the query..

Any magic idea ? :)

Thank you in advance
M

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use a string literal, like this:

`=query(G2:I; "select 'Classe 1', G, H, I where H = 'male' and I = 2000 label 'Classe 1' 'Added' "; 1)`